# Does TensorFlow version affect Neural Network model size?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to reproduce results done by my colleague from a few months back. I fed the same input files as my colleague, into a script for training the neural network. However, the output model is extremely different in file size compared to my colleague's NN model. What can possibly be the cause of this?

If inputs are all the same, could it be that a different TensorFlow version caused the difference in model file size?

Note that this is not a seed problem, as the model file sizes are significantly different.

Comment: Maybe the earlier model was quantized for a smaller size.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "quantized for a smaller size"? Thank you.

Comment: Could be a newer version has a richer metadata structure, or there was some processing done to the inputs prior to being processed, or perhaps the serialized model was compressed in one case or the other.  What would be more interesting is the result -- does the testing show any differences after the training between versions?

Comment: The test results are slightly worse. The inputs are exactly the same though.

Comment: The raw weights should not change in size. Try writing those to disk. If they change then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Are you saying that you are using exactly the same training script?

Comment: Without more context (like actual code), this is too broad to be answerable. You are basically asking us to guess what the problem is.

Comment: Please give us more information I would be interested to help you to understand what is happening. if you found the solution would be awesome if you give us code from 2 CNN and where the problem was